# Cancel crashed vista update

Tags: windows-vista, crash, updates

This morning my Windows Vista was updating, after that I restart the computer to "apply the updates". Windows freezes at the update screen and I cannot go any further (it's stuck at 61% for several hours). Now is there a way that I can cancel the pending updates, I don't need them anyway? Or do I have to reinstall that thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is to restart and load up in safe mode and then restart the computer so that it doesn't apply updates